# Grab Closeout Domains Using Python and GoDaddy API

Tags: python, json, godaddy-api

I'm looking to automate my domain search process, specifically targeting closeout domains. Websites like expireddomains.net offer such functionality, but I'm interested in understanding how they achieve this.

I have access to GoDaddy's API and I'm comfortable using Python to pull my own domain names. However, in searching online, I've found inconsistent answers regarding whether it's possible to pull closeout domain information.

Is there a way to extract closeout domain data using Python and GoDaddy's API, or an alternative method? If anyone has experience in this area or can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Using this to pull my own Domain names but researching can't get closeout names.

```
import requests
import json

def fetch_domain_info():
    # define the domain
    domain = 'domain.com'  # replace with the domain you want to check

    # define the status and limit
    status = 'ACTIVE'
    limit = '100'

    # define the url
    url = f"https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains?statuses={status}&limit={limit}"

    # define the headers
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'sso-key KEY:SECRETE',
    }

    # make the GET request
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

      # check the status code
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # decode the json response
        data = response.json()
        return data
    else:
        print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
        return []  # return an empty list in case of failure
```